# Странное поведение ограничений в обобщенном методе

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

Всем доброго времени суток. Может быть кто-то уже сталкивался с таким и может помочь?

```
public static class JSON
    {
        public static string Serialize_object_TO_JSON<T>(this T Entity)
         where T:ENT
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Entity);
        }

    }
```

Есть некий класс, который наследует ENT и передавать его в атрибуты можно. Дальше мне пришлось переделать метод так, чтоб она работал с коллекциями:

```
public static class JSON
        {
            public static string Serialize_object_TO_JSON<T>(this T Entity)
             where T:List<ENT>
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Entity);
            }

        }
```

После чего компилятор говорит, что ему не удалось привести тип класса, который наследуется от `ENT`, к типу `List<ENT>`.

P.S. Изначально задавать обобщение конечного класса я не могу, т.к. их довольно много, именно по этому попытался делать через наследование.

Comment: покажите, как вызываете

Comment: Если в любой части программы можно передать любую коллекцию в метод `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` и получить JSON-объект, то зачем понадобилось для отдельного семейства объектов делать свой метод сериализации? Это не дублирование?

Comment: попробуй так: `public static string Serialize_object_TO_JSON<T>(this List<T> Entity)
         where T:ENT`

Comment: @adamshakhabov В проекте присутствует множество объектов которые нужно сериализовать, в этом особой проблемы нет, но чтоб потом получить из них объекты нужно точно значить тип объекта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так, если Вам это разрешает бизнес логика:

```
public static class JSON
{
  public static string Serialize_object_TO_JSON<T>(this T Entity)
   where T : IEnumerable<ENT>
  {
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Entity);
  }
}
```

Дело в том что `List<T>` - инвариантен. И все классы в .NET инвариантны. То есть это полное соответствие типов.

> Означает, что можно использовать только изначально заданный тип. Таким образом, параметр инвариантного универсального типа не является ни ковариантным, ни контравариантным.

С другой стороны есть `IEnumerable<out T>` где тип-параметр `T` помечен как `out` - ковариантным.

> Позволяет использовать тип с большей глубиной наследования, чем задано изначально.

[Полное описание почему так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

[+1 за хороший пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107071/why-classes-that-implement-variant-interfaces-remain-invariant)

Comment: Здесь, мне кажется, не в этом дело, а в том, что `List<Descendant>` не является наследником `List<Base>`.

Comment: @Igor, ну как бы любые два `List<T>` и `List<U>` не имеют связь base-derived, или о чем Вы, не могу я правильно понять Вашу мысль?

Comment: Да, идеально. Применил в проекте - всё работает как часы. Спасибо большое за решение и за материалы по этой теме - пойду вникать :)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan - спасибо, не знал про `IEnumerable<out T>`